# Displaying the contents of a dynamic array backwards

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

So the program is supposed to do the following:
Ask the user to enter strings (max length of the string being 250), and once the user enters nothing (so basically hitting 'enter'), the program stops taking input and proceeds to display every string the user has input backwards.
Here's my code - everything works except I can't enter the `while` loop at the bottom.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char userInput[250];
    char *newSpace;
    char *array;
    int stringLength;
    int inputElems = 0;
    //Reset startingPtr back to where 'array' begins
    char *startingPtr = array - inputElems;
    // Sets endPtr to the last input element in the array
    char *endPtr = startingPtr + inputElems;

    do
    {
        puts("Please enter a string!");
        // Gets input from user
        fgets(userInput, 250, stdin);
        // Finds out the number of characters the user entered
        // + 1 to make room for the null character
        stringLength = strlen(userInput) + 1;
        // Allocate memory with the needed space
        newSpace = malloc(stringLength);
        // If malloc didn't allocate memory, display error
        if (NULL == newSpace)
        {
            puts("Error!");
        }

        // Copy user input into array
        strcpy(newSpace, userInput);
        // Save input into array
        array = newSpace;

        // For testing purposes only, this line will be deleted once I can access the array
        //puts("Here's what you wrote");
        //printf("%s", array);

        // Increase array
        array++;
        // Increase number of times user has input something
        inputElems++;

    } while(stringLength != 2);

    //puts("Testing outside");

    while (endPtr > startingPtr)
    {
        //puts("Testing inside");
        --endPtr;
        printf("%s", *endPtr);
    }

    free(newSpace);
}
```

Comment: Why `stringLength != 2`?

Comment: Because when you enter a blank string, you have the `' '` character and the `\0` (null character). So the program keeps asking for input as long as I don't type anything and hit `enter`

Comment: `array` is a pointer to a C-string. Doing `array+1` makes it point to the next character; yet, your comments make it appear you want it to be an array of char pointers.

Comment: Where am I doing `array + 1`? Edit: if you're talking about the line `array++`, isn't that what I need to do in order for the next string to not override the preceding string?

Comment: `array++` means `array+1` ... but you may want to review your basic knowledge on strings, as your above comment to @Nick is also wrong.

Comment: Well, with the space character and the null character being the input, wouldn't the length of that 'string' make it 2? I don't understand what you're trying to point out

Comment: Ugh. Okay ... 1. the character that is entered in the string when you just press "Enter" is not a space, it is (surprise!) an Enter. (You don't *check* for that, nevertheless it shows a bit of misunderstanding). Second, the length of a string containing 1 character is 1.

Comment: Then I was expressing myself incorrectly, and I see what you're saying. `stringLength != 2` makes it so that the program stops if nothing is entered. In the line `stringLength = strlen(userInput) + 1;` I'm counting the length of the string entered, and using the `+ 1` so that it saves the null character into the array. If nothing is input then there's just one character on the stream, the `\n` character, plus the `+ 1`. Is that better logic? Edit: I posted this before I saw your 'ugh, okay' reply.

Comment: I recommend changing for `while(*userInput != '\n')`

Comment: @Nick, okay, I changed it. But what's the problem between the way I originally had it and using your suggestion? Doesn't it end up working the same way?

Comment: Slightly better :-) The *name* of that variable is confusing (as at that point it is *not* "the string length"). And you really only need the (real) string length + 1 at a single point (in your `malloc` call). Now with that out of the way, read my first comment re: `array`.

Comment: So basically, the line `stringLength = strlen(userInput) + 1;` is unnecessary? And the following line would then look like so: `newSpace = malloc(stringLength + 1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop body is never executed because you never modify `endPtr` and `startingPtr` throughout the program's lifetime, they both point to the same location. Thus, `endPtr > startingPtr` will never be true.

Also, `array++` does not work the way you expect: `array` points to the first character of what the user wrote, and `array++` just moves it forward to the next character. I think you want an array of `char *`. Thus, change `char *array;` to `char *array[250];` (assuming that the user can enter at most 250 sentences).

And of course, since you can't increment an array, because an array is not a modifiable l-value, you must also keep a count for the last index written. But I see that you already have `inputElems`, that should be enough. Here's the modified code:

```
int main()
{
    char userInput[250];
    char *newSpace;
    char *array[250];
    int stringLength;
    int i;
    int inputElems = 0;

    do
    {
        puts("Please enter a string!");
        // Gets input from user
        fgets(userInput, 250, stdin);
        // Finds out the number of characters the user entered
        // + 1 to make room for the null character
        stringLength = strlen(userInput) + 1;
        // Allocate memory with the needed space
        newSpace = malloc(stringLength);
        // If malloc didn't allocate memory, display error
        if (NULL == newSpace)
        {
            puts("Error!");
        }

        // Copy user input into array
        strcpy(newSpace, userInput);
        // Save input into array
        array[inputElems] = newSpace;

        // For testing purposes only, this line will be deleted once I can access the array
        //puts("Here's what you wrote");
        //printf("%s", array);

        // Increase number of times user has input something
        inputElems++;

    } while(stringLength != 2);

    //puts("Testing outside");

    for (i = inputElems-1; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        //puts("Testing inside");
        printf("%s", array[i]);
        free(array[i]);         
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the updated loop in the end of the code. It goes through the array from end to beginning. Note that I changed the place where you call `free()`. Since we're allocating memory inside a loop, for each position in `array`, we must also `free()` every position, thus this must also be made inside a loop.

Comment: I thought the memory that needed to be 'freed' was the memory being used in the heap, not the stack?

Comment: You are correct, but note that "array" is now an array of pointers. The array itself, i.e., the 250 slots to hold 250 pointers is allocated in stack, but what these pointers store is allocated in heap, since we dynamically assigned each pointer with a call to malloc. array[i] is a pointer whose content is in heap. But the array itself, holding the addresses of these contents, is in stack and we don't need to free it.

Comment: Understood, thank you! One last thing.. is there a way to make my program work without having to change `char *array` to `char *array[250]`?

Comment: Well, the only way I can think of is to allocate a big big array and store every sentence one after the other, like this: "Sentence one\nSentence2\nSentence3", etc... but that would make it harder for you to print them in reverse order; it would make your program harder to read, and it would definitely not be easy to manage. Why don't you want to use an array of pointers?

Comment: It's not that I don't at all, I just wanted to see if there was a different way of doing it because as of late, I've been using pointers to point to the first and last items of an array, and traversing through the array that way.

Comment: What I showed you is sort of the conventional / traditional way to do this kind of stuff. It can be confusing for someone who never used it, but it's easy to master after some practice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. you need an array of pointers like: char *arr[10];

You can store here 10 strings from arr[0] to arr[9]. (Well not directly 10 strings, but the pointers to them)

arr[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char * length_of_string));

strncpy(arr[0], your_string, length_of_string);

When just print arr[9] to arr[0].

mfg

Comment: The first way. So if I were to type `one`, `two`, `three`, the output would be `three`, `two`, `one`.

Comment: @Progga, I know you're new to StackOverflow. Welcome to this amazing website, but please don't post answers to ask for clarification. Answers are supposed to give out a solution to the OP.

Comment: sorry, i cant see a "comment"-button under the question? I can i add a comment instead of an answer? I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hum, sorry, I didn't remember that you need some more reputation to be able to comment.